# Applying random forest model to a dataframe with multiple types of data

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to solve the following classification problem: one has a large (~2-10 GB) .csv file containing a data frame of various types. In particular, there are columns containing numeric floats as well as date/times, text strings and discrete parameters from a small set. There is also a binary parameter classifying each entry which one wants to predict in the future using the machine learning approach.

Now, what would be the most appropriate tool for this job? After some research I settled on scikit-learn as the main option, but if there is other software radically better suited for the task, I'd be happy to switch.

Secondly, is the random forest approach the best way to go here? I realise there are probably many factors influencing the answer to this question, but from playing around with a few tutorials and looking at the scikit-learn flowchart I am currently leaning towards random forests.

Assuming one uses random forests, how exactly one should prepare these data in order for the model to make sense of it? From what I understand, scikit-learn takes only numerical floats as inputs for the model. While I could discretise date/time and other discrete fields with something like OneHotEncoder, it is not immediately clear what to do with text fields since the processing, I suppose, is very different. (I have looked at the bag-of-words approach, but being someone new to the field I fell it a bit hard to grasp right away.) Is there a meaningful way of transforming text fields for use in the model?

Finally, what is the best way of dealing with large datasets for this task? While for the start their size could be limited to something fitting inside runtime memory, ideally there should be a way to extend the training set to be very large.

Apologies for the vagueness of some questions. Since I am quite new to data science in general, I would appreciate if you could include actual working examples in your answers. Thanks!

Comment: Vitaly, you hit the nail the head on your apology.  This question is too vague for anyone to give you meaningful, insightful help.  Scikit-learn is perfectly suited for data on the scale of GB, but unless you can give a better description of what you're hoping to classify, and why a particular set of characteristics may be predictive, it's tough to comment further.

Comment: @j.a.gartner there is reason to believe that certain words/n-grams in text fields are associated with triggering the binary parameter (say, B). As to why a set of characteristics may be predictive, that's one part of what I'm trying to find out -- which combinations of characteristics, if any, predict the desired B. The total number of columns in the data frame is not very large, about 5 to 10, and my question was mostly about meaningfully transforming them into a shape on which I could act with random forests.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to remember when we use Random Forest is when you use a categorical feature for training it shouldn't have more than 53 categories. Sometimes RandomForest takes numerical data as categorical. To overcome that make sure to convert all categorical as factors using this command.

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].astype('category')
```

Lastly, make sure that all the levels in a categorical feature are presnent in both train and test data or else the model cannot hadle such situations.

I think you might get the model running if you can use any server(as the model can use the servers processing capacity to its fullest) and deploy on that and let it run before you leave for the day, before deploying make sure that you have tested the code on sample data. So, that it won't abend with some error.

Do let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything you need on scikit documentation and tutorial pages. 
Consider using a different algorithm using this map http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/

For text variables use a vectorizer.